# How To Keep Upload Image inside post folder in Public/Storage

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to keep my uploaded image into `public_html/storage/post/`. but now this code not working for me and upload into the `direct public_html/`

```
 $image = $request->file('image');
        $slug = str_slug($request->title);
        if(isset($image))
        {
//            make unipue name for image
            $currentDate = Carbon::now()->toDateString();
            $imageName  = $slug.'-'.$currentDate.'-'.uniqid().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();

            if(!Storage::disk('public')->exists('post'))
            {
                Storage::disk('public')->makeDirectory('post');
            }

            $postImage = Image::make($image)->save($imageName);
            Storage::disk('public')->put('post/'.$imageName,$postImage);

        } else {
            $imageName = "default.png";
        }
```

Comment: have you done php artisan storage:link ?

Comment: yes i **Done** Storage:link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Fixed in `config/filesystems.php` public root to 
`'root' => public_path().'/../public_html/storage',`